# <app> would like to access data from other apps - macOS Sonoma

Tags: objective-c, macos, security, macos-sonoma

i have a properly sandboxed and codesigned app for macOS in objective-c. On Sonoma (macOS 14) i keep getting the dialog " would like to access data from other apps". According to Apple Developer this is a new security related message on macOS 14.2.

See here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/742147

My App is developed according to Apples guidelines. E.g. using Open or SavePanels, Security scoped Bookmarks and so on. It does NOT try to access anothers app AppContainer (so this is whats confusing me).

My app controls another one by the usage of Apple Events but i do not try to access the apps AppContainer to read/write data.

CodeSigning uses a valid DeveloperIDApplication signature, Notarization also succeeds every time.

I searched through Developer Docs, Forums and so on and I am quite lost, just seeing that others got this issue too.

Any hint towards the right direction is very much appreciated.

Comment: Does the app you are controlling have access to user data?

Comment: @red_menace Entitlemenets are set accordingly.